# Interesting places to see around (not in) Valencia?

Tags: sightseeing, spain, valencia

What are some interesting places to see that are accessible from Valencia for a reasonable price?

I'm not looking for things in Valencia proper (suggestions are still very welcome, but it's a lot easier to google for those), but places easily accessible from Valencia by train/bus/etc.  The time of visit is December, approx. 1 week.

Examples of what we find interesting (I'm only including this as a rough guideline for people who answer, as I'd expect question about this): seeing local life, possibly villages, I liked the zoo in other cities, *easy* hiking (as I'm not alone), local food.  Examples of what I don't find interesting: nightlife.

Currently I have the choice between staying 3.5 or 6.5 days, I'd lean for 7 if I can find some things to see outside Valencia too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok then, some suggestions, as I've been to Valencia a couple of times.

West of Valencia is Requena, a fantastic little Spanish town.
The night before La Tomatina is the festival of water and wine, but as you're going in December, you can just enjoy the town itself.
It used to be a Moorish fortress, and parts of the town date from the 13th century. All sorts of random little streets and twists and turns.

Closer, but still west of Valencia again is Buñol, where La Tomatina occurs. Again, nice town to walk around and explore, cool squares to sit with a coffee and soak it up.
I spent several hours walking around here trying to find anyone who would let us use a phone, after being pickpocketed at La Tomatina, so I know it well.
At least if you go in December there won't be passed-out Aussies everywhere ;)

90km north of Valencia are some hot springs.  I wanted to go, but found it really difficult to get information on them, and didn't have much time anyway. But they sounded incredible.

Finally, and I know this is vague and really unlike me as normally place names are easy, but there's a Unesco heritage site - a castle fort village place on a hill.  It's SPECTACULAR.  But for the life of me I can't remember the name.  It's 2 hours by car from Valencia.
My searching has revealed [Xàtiva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_of_J%C3%A1tiva) which seems to pretty much match it and looks amazing, but [the images](http://www.360cities.net/image/castle-of-xativa-valencia-spain#-178.35,21.01,67.8) don't jog any memories currently.  Still, it looks incredible too :)

Ok, after finding [this blog](http://beer-travels.com/index.php?ac=05&entry=10) I'm now a little more convinced that it may well be the right castle.

Also, and I know you didn't request it, but in Valencia, go see the Holy Grail, and the new area of Valencia is spectacular and well worth a walk.  You can also go down to the docks and see the America's Cup Village with all the companies that compete - Team New Zealand, Oracle and the like.

Comment: That castle fort village – are you sure it's a UNESCO site? In that case it's probably the [Historic Walled Town of Cuenca](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/781/). That's the only one within a couple of hours drive from Valencia that matches your description (see [map of heritage sites in Spain](http://whc.unesco.org/en/statesparties/es)).

Comment: AH!!! After hunting through my photos and checking with the friend I travelled with, the place is Guadalest (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Castell_de_Guadalest)

Comment: Xativa is sooo cool, I highly recommend it to everyone. My advise is to try to get there earlier, before tourist bus starts working. You will have a chance to see the castle without annoying crowds, only by yourself. It was great experience for me, because more popupal places are usually crowded and you don't have a change to enjoy the place by yourself.

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm trying to figure out which are the hot springs you talk about, but no idea.. Do you remember any data? Name? Any village near? I'm from Valencia and I'm really intrigued :)

Comment: As I said, I found it really difficult to find info on them.  All I know is that they're up there.  I saw them mentioned in guide books, in Wikitravel and google but always just in passing as "the hot springs for a day trip 90km north" style.  If you do manage to locate them - I was mainly restricted to English resources, please do update us! :)

Comment: NB Xàtiva is only one hour from Valencia by train or car. Other worthwhile castles in the area include Sagunto (20 minutes by car, 35 by train) and Peñiscola (1.5 to 2 hours by train, also possible by coach).

Answer (score 4):

There are many things to do outside of Valencia.  If you like to walk in the nature, there are many hiking trails in the surrounding mountains, less than 50km away.  Villages are also beautiful and charming.  If you're looking for something different, head to the hot springs, north or Valencia and swim there.  You can also dive into the local Spanish life and stop for tapas or go to a running of the bulls event, usually part of the yearly festival of any village around Valencia city.

Comment: Are these hiking trails accessible by public transport?  My Valencia trip is finished, but I wouldn't mind to go back some day if I got the chance :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, there are two or three trains (RENFE Cercanías) and busses (Metrobus) per day which stop at some of the villages of the Sierra de Calderona. Try searching for transport to e.g. Segorbe or Navajas.

Answer (score 2):

I am an American living here. I have done all of these things and I recommend them 100%.

My personal favorite is the hot springs. It is called Montanejos. About an hour through some beautiful windy todas in the mountains. Crystal clear water nice and warm with even a cliff to jump off if you've got the huevos. I went in February and it was awesome.

I also stayed in guadalest once. Beautiful views and castle but I've just done the mountain, there are some rad springs to swim in with lots of waterfalls. It's very cold, I recommend going in summer. Have fun!